# Views content pane configuration problems after upgrade to organic groups 7.x-2.3

Tags: organic-groups, views

Ever since I upgraded from OG 7.x-1.5 to 7.x-2.3, the views content pane for my groups has been completely screwed up. I've been researching this for weeks with zero success. In the previous version of OG, I'd set up a content pane to deliver posts written by group members to the appropriate group pages. Now, however, all of the posts from all of the groups are showing up in every group.

I've tried all different kinds of contextual filter and relationship combinations within Views, but the ones that seem the most consistent across the different forum posts I've seen (and using OG Extras as a rough guide) are these:

Contextual filter: "(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group ID" (with these configurations: Relationship: OG membership from node/Provide default value: Type: Current OG group from context/Group Type: Node)/Specify Validation Criteria: OG Group)

Relationship: OG membership: OG membership from Node

In the "Pane Settings" area, under "Argument Input" I have "From Context" and the Required Context is "OG Membership ID"

Under "Filter Criteria" I have "Content Published (Yes)" and "(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group_type (= Node)"

This gives me two results which are not wanted:

1) A bulleted list of the group numbers with the number of posts in parentheses beside them and
 2) This bulleted list is on the landing page of every single group

Instead, I want the posts written by members of each particular group to show up on the landing page for that group.

In the node I'm overriding to display my content pane, I'm having trouble figuring out the "Context" and "Relationships" settings (I'm using Panels 7.x-3.3, in case that matters). The only OG-related relationship in 7.x-2.x is "OG membership from a group node and user", but when I try to add that as a relationship, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   og_membership_from_group_and_user_context() (line 28 of
>   .../modules/og/plugins/relationships/og_membership_from_group_and_user.inc

And I have no idea what context to add here. In short, I'm really confused. Can someone please give me a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Really? No one else is having a similar issue? I really need help with this if anyone knows a work-around. I still can't get the contextual filter to show the content that's specific to each group. Might it be because my views content pane isn't talking to the pane itself? I read a few places that you don't have to set up the context or relationship in the pane anymore, but is that true? What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *panel*, not *pane*.

Comment: Did you sort this? I'm getting the same Notice errors.